# How to simplify this cube root in denominator expression?

Tags: roots, radicals, factoring

I have the expression:

$$\large\frac{1}{x^2 + \sqrt[3]{2x} + \sqrt[3]4}$$

I'm not sure how to simplify this, because it seems difficult to remove the radical from the denominator.

I know $\sqrt[3]4$ reduces to $\sqrt[3]2 \cdot \sqrt[3]2$
but that doesn't seem to get me too far.

Thanks

Comment: Your expression is not clear. When using \sqrt[3]{...}, remember to put what should be inside the root in the place of the ... Also, check the parenthesis.

Comment: Ah yes, my bad, fixed it!

Comment: It is still not clear whether it is $(\sqrt[3]{2})x$ leading to nice Luca's solution or $2x$ inside the cube root (as you wrote) which does not simplify so well.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\begin{gathered}
  \frac{1}
{{\left( {x^2  + \sqrt[3]{2}x + \sqrt[3]{4}} \right)}} = \frac{{\left( {x - \sqrt[3]{2}} \right)}}
{{\left( {x^2  + \sqrt[3]{2}x + \sqrt[3]{4}} \right)\left( {x - \sqrt[3]{2}} \right)}} =  \hfill \\
   \hfill \\
   = \frac{{\left( {x - \sqrt[3]{2}} \right)}}
{{x^3 - 2}} \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
$$

using $$(a^3-b^3)=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$$

Comment: This is probably right... More precisely, it is correct if instead of $\sqrt[3]{2x}$ the OP actually meant $\sqrt[3]{2} x$.

Comment: Yep, that's what I mean, thanks!

Comment: This is the right form. Sorry for my typos

Comment: resulting formula is not homogeneous in degree, denominator should be in $x^3$.

Comment: Yes, of course! Sorry again. I'm very tired and I get a lot of typos. Better I stop here. Sorry again